# Return a LINQ query with column values as name,value pairs

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a Table to store constants with columns(Name, Value). How do I go about getting the result of LINQ query in name value format like (Name = Value) so I can obtain the values like

```
Var thisVal = VarCollection("Name")
```

Hope this is clear.

Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a compiler handy to test this, but it'll go something like:

```
var VarCollection = (from t in Table
                    select new { t.Name, t.Value})
                    .ToLookup(t=>t.Name, t=>t.Value);
```

UPDATE: Upon reflection, I'm pretty sure that can be reduced to just:

```
var VarColelction = Table.ToLookup(t=>t.Name, t=>t.Value);
```

Comment: Assuming his LINQ query has no where clause.

Comment: This is my final query I went the dictionary way seemed much more familiar.

var VarColelction = Table.ToDictionary(t=>t.Name, t=>t.Value);

Answer (score 0):

You could use a select to put them into a KeyValuePair and then put those into a Hash (basically a set of KeyValuePairs), then refer to the variables by name.